# Update manager history and rollback options? (trying to resolve touchpad issues)

Tags: updates, touchpad

I'm having issues with my touchpad on my laptop.  It doesn't function properly.  Clicking seems to work fine, but moving the cursor to the left is very skittish.   To the right it appears to work just fine.  I move it left, and the cursor jumps right.  I had this issue during the install process, but it seemed to go a away after the first boot and update.  It has been working several weeks with out a problem.

Yesterday (2/27/2012) I was prompted by the Update Manager to install some updates.  I think the touchpad stopped working properly after next reboot.

Currently I navigate the system by the keyboard and an external mouse.  I want to use the touchpad again.

I have searched the forums and found a number of people complaining about touchpad issues, with suggested workarounds, but I want try backing out the latest updates to see if the problem goes away.

Is there an easy way to rollback these updates?

HP Pavillion DM4-2070
Ubuntu 11.10

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All actions with apt (apt-get) are logged. These files are available in /var/log/apt/. To view the most recent history log, execute:

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
```

These logs gets rotated (every month I guess), old files will be suffixed with a number and compressed. So to view the next history log, use:

```
zless /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

To view the logs available:

```
ls -la /var/log/apt/
```

You will have to examine them to determine the latest.
Or go to the Ubuntu Software Center and check the history
[image]